# Cast List<T> to List<Interface>

Tags: c#, .net, interface, casting

```
public interface IDic
{
    int Id { get; set; }
    string Name { get; set; }
}
public class Client : IDic
{

}
```

How can I cast `List<Client>` to `List<IDic>`?

Answer (score 316, accepted):

You can't *cast* it (preserving reference identity) - that would be unsafe. For example:

```
public interface IFruit {}

public class Apple : IFruit {}
public class Banana : IFruit {}

...

List<Apple> apples = new List<Apple>();
List<IFruit> fruit = apples; // Fortunately not allowed
fruit.Add(new Banana());

// Eek - it's a banana!
Apple apple = apples[0];
```

Now you can convert a `List<Apple>` to an `IEnumerable<IFruit>` in .NET 4 / C# 4 due to covariance, but if you want a `List<IFruit>` you'd have to create a *new* list. For example:

```
// In .NET 4, using the covariance of IEnumerable<T>
List<IFruit> fruit = apples.ToList<IFruit>();

// In .NET 3.5
List<IFruit> fruit = apples.Cast<IFruit>().ToList();
```

But this is *not* the same as casting the original list - because now there are two *separate* lists. This is safe, but you need to understand that changes made to one list *won't* be seen in the other list. (Modifications to the *objects* that the lists refer to will be seen, of course.)

Comment: like they're 'still in the building'!

Comment: What is the difference between doing the covariance tolist and doing new List<IFruit>(); then a foreach over the original list and adding each item to the IFruit list?  In the foreach way... the object reference would be the same, correct? So... if that is true, it makes little sense to me personally that you can't just directly cast the whole list. ?

Comment: @RobertNoack: What do you mean by "the object reference"? The object reference of each *element* is the same, but that's not the same as casting the list reference itself. Suppose you could cast the reference, so that you had a reference of compile-time type `List<IFruit>` which was actually a reference to a `List<Apple>`. What would you expect to happen if you added a `Banana` reference to that `List<IFruit>`?

Comment: Oh. I think I need to learn how to read. I thought the original answer said that the objects in the list would be deep copied and recreated which didn't make sense to me. But I clearly missed the part where only a new list is created with the same objects.

Comment: Why i can't use `ToList` and `Cast` (i'n use .net4). It not show in recommend. Or i missing some namespace?

Comment: @TrươngQuốcKhánh: I have no idea what *any* of your code looks like, or whether you have a `using` directive for `System.Linq`, or what you're trying to call it on, I'm not sure how you expect me to be able to help. I suggest you do more research, and if you're still stuck, you ask a question with a [mcve].

Comment: I can't see why you would expect/not expect a banana if you assigned an apply from your List<Apple>...  // Eek - it's a banana!
Apple apple = apples[0];    However, it is conceivable that List<IFruit> could contain either an apple or a banana, so you shouldn't be able to assign a list of IFruit to a list of Apple, in the same way you can't just assign a IFruit to an Apple without casting (and risk it being a banana!)... But why not the other way round?

Comment: @JamesJoyce: It's reasonable to expect a `List<Apple>` to only contain apples. Therefore it's surprising when it turns out it's a banana. It would basically be a violation of a sensible type system. (Bear in mind that you may not be aware of the code that's adding a banana.)

Comment: @JamesJoyce: "But why not the other way round?" Precisely because that's how you end up adding a banana - if you could perform that assignment. Which statement in `List<IFruit> fruit = apples; fruit.Add(new Banana());` would you expect not to work?

Comment: Aaahhh - now I understand. Its the same list!!! My bad. I was forgetting that critical point. Thanks for taking the time!

Comment: You could always create your own custom typecast if that's the syntax you want to use. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1407689/how-do-i-provide-custom-cast-support-for-my-class

Comment: Guess down-voters were not happy that you didn't mention variance only applies to generic interface and delegates but not to generic classes:)

Comment: Coming from Java and given C# doesn't have type erasure, I would expect it to just throw an exception when trying to add a `Banana`. Basically when casting up to a `List<IFruit>` it would add type checks to ensure everything was the correct type.

Comment: @thecodewarrior: The point of generics is broadly to make things safe at *compile-time*. C# generics are safer in this sense than C# arrays (which *do* have reference type variance, unfortunately).

Comment: Btw, if you start off with a List of IFruit, can you add Apples and Bananas to it? How does that work?

Comment: @KevinVictor: The same as if you have a variable of type `IFruit` and assign a reference to an `Apple` or `Banana` as the value. (I'm not sure what kind of answer you're looking for in terms of "How does that work".)

Comment: @JonSkeet I've noticed that `List<Apple>` IS implicitly castable to `IEnumerable<IFruit>` - but not `IList<IFruit>`. Why's that?

Comment: @Extragorey: Because `IEnumerable<T>` is a *covariant* interface, and `IList<IFruit>` isn't. It's safe to convert a `List<Apple>` to `IEnumerable<IFruit>` because all you can do is take things out of an `IEnumerable<IFruit>`, and every `Apple` is an `IFruit` - but with `IList<T>` there's a setter, so you could write `fruitList.Add(new Banana())` which clearly isn't safe.

Comment: @JonSkeet Ahh I see, so casting to `IEnumerable` is still useful for read-only usage.

Comment: I really just don't like the fact List<Apple> can't be a param for a function asking for List<IFruit>... to me that seems like a language weakness.

Comment: @Shiv: Would you prefer to wait until execution time for it to fail when that method then calls `list.Add(new Banana());`? (If the method only needs to read from the list, it should have a parameter of type `IReadOnlyList<IFruit>` instead, at which point it's fine.)

Comment: @JonSkeet was trying to use List<T> readonly with the .ForEach capability as well... guess we can work around that. If readonly is required to give compile time safety I'm happy with that compromise. Makes a lot more sense.

Comment: @Shiv: It's trivial to add your own `ForEach` extension method for `IReadOnlyList<T>` should you wish. I'd suggest reading https://ericlippert.com/2009/05/18/foreach-vs-foreach/ before doing so though.

Answer (score 12):

I too had this problem and after reading Jon Skeet's answer I modified my code from using `List<T>` to use `IEnumerable<T>`. Although this does not answer the OP's original question of *How can I cast `List<Client>` to `List<IDic>`*, it does avoid the need to do so and thus may be helpful to others who encounter this issue. This of course assumes that the code that requires the use of `List<IDic>` is under your control.

E.g.:

```
public void ProcessIDic(IEnumerable<IDic> sequence)
{
   // Implementation
}
```

Instead of:

```
public void ProcessIDic(List<IDic> list)
{
   // Implementation
}
```

Answer (score 10):

A Cast iterator and .ToList():

`List<IDic> casted = input.Cast<IDic>().ToList()` will do the trick.

Originally I said covariance would work - but as Jon has rightly pointed out; no it won't!

And originally I also stupidly left off the `ToList()` call

Comment: `Cast` returns an `IEnumerable<T>`, not a `List<T>` - and no, covariance *won't* allow this conversion, because it would be unsafe - see my answer.

Comment: From the page you linked to: "Only interface types and delegate types can have variant type parameters"

Comment: @Jon - I'd realised the `ToList()` was missing before reading your comment; but yes as you've shown of course Covariance won't work!  Doh!

Comment: Right. Covariance can still help, as it means you don't need the `Cast` call in .NET 4, so long as you specify the type argument to `ToList`.

Answer (score 5):

If you can use LINQ then you can do this...

```
List<Client> clientList = new List<Client>();
List<IDic> list = clientList.Select(c => (IDic)c).ToList();
```

Answer (score 5):

```
List<Client> listOfA = new List<Client>();
List<IDic> list = listOfA.Cast<IDic>().ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

**[OfType](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.oftype)**

You can try something like:

```
        using (var dbContext = YourDatabaseContext())
        {
            var list = dbContext.Clients.Where(x => x.Happy)
                .OfType<IDic>()
                .ToList();
        }
```

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.oftype

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need to modify the contents of the original list, you can implicitly convert a List into a IReadOnlyList which will let you iterate over it's contents as IDics without creating a new list.

```
List<Client> myClients = new List<Client>();
myClients.Add(new Client());

IReadOnlyList<IDic> castedClients = myClients;
foreach(IDic val in castedClients)
{
    //do something;
}
```

The conversion can also occur while simply returning the list like so :

```
public IReadOnlyList<IDic> getClientsAsIDic()
{
    return myClients;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Its only possible by creating new `List<IDic>` and transfering all elements.

Comment: Any comment why downvoted, since general meaning is the same as all other answers?

Comment: My guess would be you got downvoted because you said it was only possible to create a new list, but others have posted to the contrary... not my downvote though)

Comment: Well they do create new lists but not with new operator which doesn't change fact that they do.

Answer (score 0):

In .Net 3.5, you can do the following:

```
List<ISomeInterface> interfaceList = new List<ISomeInterface>(list.Cast<ISomeInterface>());
```

The constructor for List in this case takes an IEnumerable. 
**list** though is only convertible to IEnumerable. Even though **myObj** may be convertible to ISomeInterface the type IEnumerable is not convertible to IEnumerable.

Comment: The issue is this makes a copy of the list, most of the time you want to do operations on the original list

Answer (score 0):

If you want to process the original list without creating a separated reference, you could define the generic method like this:

```
public void DoIterate<T>(List<T> myCollection) where T : IDic
{
   foreach (T item in myCollection)
   {
      //update a property of interface
      item.Name = "new Name";
   }
}
```

Calling this method above to process the list without having to cast specific object to interface:

```
List<Client> clients = new List<Client>();
DoIterate(clients);
```