# Only allowing specific object types to be passed into a method based on a derived class type

Tags: c#, derived-class

I have a base class which has a method call `AddFruit` that takes a class of `Fruit` type and processes it in a general way.

```
    public abstract class Foo
    {
        protected List<ProcessedFruit> processedFruit = new List<ProcessedFruit>();

        public void AddFruit(Fruit o)       
        {
            // Process fruit

            processedFruit.Add(o);
        }

        public void Update()
        {
            // Do base class specific stuff here
            OnUpdate();
        }

        protected abstract void OnUpdate();
    }

    public class AppleBar : Foo
    {
        public AppleBar()
            :base(){}

        protected override void OnUpdate() { }
    }

    public class BananaBar : Foo
    {
        public BananaBar()
            :base(){}

        protected override void OnUpdate() { }
    }
```

Any class which derives from `Foo` is updated in a non general way and will use the list of `ProcessedFruit` in a different manner.

`Fruit` can be added and processed any time after the `Bar` class has been instantiated.

```
    public abstract class Fruit
    {

    }

    public class Banana : Fruit
    {

    }

    public class Apple : Fruit
    {

    }
```

I'm wondering, is it possible to only allow a particular type of `Fruit` class to be added based on the derived `Bar` class type?

For example:

- `AppleBar` will only allow the adding of type `Apple`
- `BananaBar` will only allow the adding of type `Banana`

I understand that I could override the `AddFruit` method but I would like the processing to remain in the base class and would like to avoid calling `base.AddFruit` in the overridden methods associated with the `BananaBar` and `AppleBar` derived classes.

I also wish to avoid checking the type of `Fruit` using `GetType()`.

Ideally I would like something as follows:

```
var o = new AppleBar()

// This has to be an Apple and intellisense can recognise this 
o.AddFruit(...);
```

Is this possible?

**Edit:**

I am having problems with the following using generics:

```
 List<Foo<Fruit>> commands = new List<Foo<Fruit>>(10);

 commands.Add(new AppleBar());    // Can't be added
 commands.Add(new BananaBar());   // Can't be added
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, why is Fruit a subclass of ProcessedFruit?

Comment: Because my naming convention is pretty terrible.  I was trying to keep it straightforward and not use my class names.

Comment: If you have a valid use for holding onto a collection of the different `commands`, you could create an interface for your shared behavior, and the List would be of the interface type (such as `List<IFoo>`).

Answer (score 6):

The easiest way to do this is with a generic type parameter on the base class, which then gets filled in with a specific type by the inheriting class:

```
public abstract class Foo<T> where T : Fruit
{
    protected List<ProcessedFruit> processedFruit = new List<ProcessedFruit>();

    public void AddFruit(T o)       
    {
        // Process fruit

        processedFruit.Add(o);
    }

    public void Update()
    {
        // Do base class specific stuff here
        OnUpdate();
    }

    protected abstract void OnUpdate();
}

public class AppleBar : Foo<Apple>
{
    //...
}
```

**Update**

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8925400/cast-listt-to-listinterface/8925442#8925442) for an explanation of why you can't add an `AppleBar` to a `List<Foo<Fruit>>`

Comment: If I wanted to keep a `List` of the Foo classes.  How would I then add the derived classes to that list?  For example: `var fooList = new List<Foo<Fruit>();`  `fooList.Add(new AppleBar());`  The `Add` method does not work in this case?

Comment: Can you create a new List<Foo<T>> where T : Fruit? (I don't know, and I'm on a Mac right now).

Comment: @user1423893 Yeah that won't work because `fooList` is a list of `Foo<Fruit>`s, not a list of `Foo<Apple>`s. You can't have a list like that which maintains type-safety. If you could add an `AppleBar` to a `List<Foo<Fruit>>`, then you could do `Foo<Fruit> appleBar = fooList.First()`. Then because you have a `Foo<Fruit>` rather than a `Foo<Apple>`, you'd expect to be able to do `appleBar.AddFruit(new Banana())`

Comment: I think I need to rethink my class structure after reading that answer.  Thank you for your help and answer.

Comment: @user1423893 Read up on generic covariance and contravariance, but they only help in certain situations and this doesn't look like one of them. But yes, trying to keep classes of different types in a single list is usually a design smell

Comment: In this case, it certainly is :)