# Efficiently return IList<Interface> from List<T> (avoid casting from List<T> to List<I>)

Tags: c#, interface, casting

I have the following code:

```
public interface ISomeObject
{
     IList<ISomeObject> Objects { get; }
}
public class SomeObject : ISomeObject
{
    public SomeObject()
    {
        Objects = new List<SomeObject>();
    }
    public List<SomeObject> Objects
    {
         get;
         set;
    }
    IList<ISomeObject> ISomeObject.Objects
    {    
        get 
        {
            // What to do here?
            // return Objects; // This doesn't work
            return Objects.Cast<ISomeObject>().ToList(); // Works, but creates a copy each time.
         }
    }
```

`SomeObject` has a public property `Objects` that returns a List of class type. Clients knowing that class type can use that to do whatever they want. Clients only knowing about `ISomeObject` can use the `Objects` property only to get an `IList<ISomeObject>`. Because it is not allowed to cast `List<SomeObject>` to `IList<ISomeObject>` (due to the [apple and banana issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8925400/cast-listt-to-listinterface)) I need a way of converting that. The default way, using a Cast.ToList() works, but has the downside that it creates a new List each time the property is evaluated, which may be expensive. Changing `ISomeObject.Objects` to return an `IEnumerable<ISomeObject>` has the other downside that the client can't use indexing any more (which is quite relevant in my use case). And using Linq's ElementAt() call repeatedly is expensive, when used on an IEnumerable.

Has anybody got an idea on how to avoid either problem? 
(of course, making `SomeObject` known everywhere is not an option).

Comment: If indexing is an important use case for the consumers, why doesn't the `ISomeObject` interface also have an indexer as well as/instead of the `Objects` property?

Comment: You could/should implement a class similar to `ReadOnlyCollection<T>` to act as a proxy. Considering that it would be read only, it could be covariant, like IEnumerable

Comment: Why do you believe that Linq's ElementAt will be a performance issue? It is optimised to check if the `IEnumerable` is in fact a `IList` and than calls the indexed property. See the source code: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,7db56d44563d8761

Comment: @RandRandom (Copied from my comment on NineBerry's answer) `ElementAt<ISomeObject>` does check if the object behind `IEnumerable<ISomeObject>` supports `IList<ISomeObject>`, but it won't support that (it only supports `IList<SomeObject>`), so that check is just a waste of time.

Comment: @hvd Already saw your comment, and upvoted it - never thought about it.

Comment: @RandRandom; I was just thinking about this as well, but unfortunately, it doesn't work...

Comment: @Liam: No, the given link explains just the solution I _don't_ want to use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could/should implement a class similar to `ReadOnlyCollection<T>` to act as a proxy. Considering that it would be read only, it could be "covariant" (not language-side, but logically, meaning that it could proxy a `TDest` that is a subclass/interface of `TSource`) and then `throw NotSupportedException()` for all the write methods.

Something like this (code untested):

```
public class CovariantReadOlyList<TSource, TDest> : IList<TDest>, IReadOnlyList<TDest> where TSource : class, TDest
{
    private readonly IList<TSource> source;

    public CovariantReadOlyList(IList<TSource> source)
    {
        this.source = source;
    }

    public TDest this[int index] { get => source[index]; set => throw new NotSupportedException(); }

    public int Count => source.Count;

    public bool IsReadOnly => true;

    public void Add(TDest item) => throw new NotSupportedException();

    public void Clear() => throw new NotSupportedException();

    public bool Contains(TDest item) => IndexOf(item) != -1;

    public void CopyTo(TDest[] array, int arrayIndex)
    {
        // Using the nuget package System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe
        // source.CopyTo(Unsafe.As<TSource[]>(array), arrayIndex);
        // We love to play with fire :-)

        foreach (TSource ele in source)
        {
            array[arrayIndex] = ele;
            arrayIndex++;
        }
    }

    public IEnumerator<TDest> GetEnumerator() => ((IEnumerable<TDest>)source).GetEnumerator();

    public int IndexOf(TDest item)
    {
        TSource item2 = item as TSource;

        if (ReferenceEquals(item2, null) && !ReferenceEquals(item, null))
        {
            return -1;
        }

        return source.IndexOf(item2);
    }

    public void Insert(int index, TDest item)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }

    public bool Remove(TDest item)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }

    public void RemoveAt(int index)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

Use it like:

```
IList<string> strs = new List<string>();
IList<object> objs = new CovariantReadOlyList<string, object>(strs);
```

Comment: Any reason why `IndexOf` isnt implemented as `return source.IndexOf((TSource)item);` ?

Comment: @RandRandom You can't upcast an unknown `item` (`item` is a parameter). In the example given: `objs.IndexOf(new object())`

Comment: @RandRandom I could TSource item2 = item as TSource; and use the `is` operator... but then i'll have to check for `null`, and the code will still be unreadable.

Comment: Not entirely sure what you mean, so I just went ahead and tested my question and it seems to work. So my index of looks like this: `public int IndexOf(TDest item) { return source.IndexOf((TSource)item); }` - the declaration of the class looks like this `var x = new CovariantReadOlyList<Foo, IFoo>(list);` - and I call `IndexOf` like this: `var index = x.IndexOf(list[1]);` which results in the same index as the `source` list has `list[1]`

Comment: @RandRandom Changed the code... It is as much ugly as before, but perhaps it will be faster, because the `IndexOf` will be executed totally internally the `source`, instead of going through the roundtrips of the enumerator.

Comment: @RandRandom Try using the `IList<string> strs = new List<string>(); IList<object> objs = new CovariantReadOlyList<string, object>(strs); objs.IndexOf(new object());`

Comment: @xanatos: Ah, and then you would create the List<SomeObject> and the CovariantReadonlyList<SomeObject, ISomeObject> both in the constructor of the containing class?

Comment: @PMF In general the `List<SomeObject>` is the real object, and when needed you return a `return new CovariantReadonlyList<SomeObject, ISomeObject>(realList)`. The creation cost of `CovariantReadonlyList` is nearly zero, because it only stores a reference to the original `List<>`

Comment: `strs.AsReadOnly()` will return such wrapper already (`ReadOnlyCollection<T>`) so I see no reason to manually implement it.

Comment: @evk The question was about IList, not IReadOnlyList. There is another response about that other option. Perhaps he need an IList because his interfaces are written in that way. IReadOnlyCollection in general is a better solution **if** you can use it

Comment: @xanatos List.AsReadOnly method returns ReadOnlyCollection (not interface). This class implements multiple interfaces, including IList (and so - is a built-in analog of what you written in this answer).  So if OP wants IList - he can still use that (though OP needs just indexer and so - IReadOnlyList is a better choice, and is also implemented by ReadOnlyCollection).

Comment: @evk List<T>.AsReadOnly() returns a IList<T>, the question is about obtaining a read only IList<baseT>.  If the question is XY then your response is good, and you should post it.

Comment: Well I realize now I'm wrong, because covariance is involved, so you cannot just `return Objects.AsReadOnly()` and leave interface as `IList<>`. Yet I still think all that is not needed and OP should just change interface to `IReadOnlyList<T>` (since he needs indexer and this interface has indexer, and is covariant in T), and do `return Objects.AsReadOnly()`. It's better in all ways.

Answer (score 3):

> Changing `ISomeObject.Objects` to return an `IEnumerable<ISomeObject>` has the other downside that the client can't use indexing any more (which is quite relevant in my use case).

Indexing isn't just supported by the `IList<T>` interface, it's also supported by the `IReadOnlyList<T>` interface. Because `IReadOnlyList<T>` doesn't allow modification, it can be (and is) covariant just like `IEnumerable<T>` is.

So, just change the return type to `IReadOnlyList<ISomeObject>` and return the original list.

Of course, nothing prevents the caller from casting the result to `List<SomeObject>`, but the caller is supposed to have full access to that list anyway, so there is no security risk.

Comment: As with some other things in .NET, I have a little sadness that `IReadOnlyList<>` wasn't supported from .NET 2.0. Many methods would have been written with a different signature, making it clear that the collection they receive/return is readonly.

Comment: This solution would work, if List<T> was implementing IReadonlyList<T> (it seems it doesn't), so I couldn't do this without the wrapper from xanatos' answer

Comment: @PMF [`List<T>` does implement `IReadOnlyList<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx) though.

Comment: @PMF it indeed implements `IReadOnlyList` in both full .NET and in .NET Core. Even more, `List<T>` has method `AsReadOnly` which will return `ReadOnlyCollection<T>`. This is built-in wrapper similar to what is provided in xanatos answer, so there is no reason to manually implement it. So correct way would be to change interface to `IReadOnlyList<T>`, and then do `return Objects.AsReadOnly()` (this method does no copying).

Comment: @Evk: You are right. Looks like I have been looking at an old version of the MSDN.

Comment: For reasons unrelated to the question (the actual code has some further goodies, like MarshalByRef behavior etc.), I still prefer xanatos' solution.

Answer (score 0):

You may want try to encapsulate your `List<SomeObject>` making it an implementation detail and return `IReadOnlyList<SomeObject>` instead. Then `SomeObject` to `ISomeObject` cast want be unnecessary in interface implementation as well due to `IReadOnlyList` variance — you'll be able to return your `Objects` as  `IReadOnlyList<ISomeObject>` .

Then just add some operations to mutate your underlying list like `Add` or `Remove` to container type if those are required.

Also I should mention that interfaces are not so good for restriction — evil consumer can easily cast your `ISomeObject` to `SomeObject` and do everything he wants, probably, you should reconsider your design. You'd better stick to such things as immutability and encapsulation for providing usable api. Explicitly use mutable builders then for immutable classes where it's reasonable.

Comment: In the real case, ISomeObject is declared in another assembly than SomeObject. The clients don't reference the assembly with SomeObject in it, so they can't do that cast. (And SomeObject should later be internal)

Comment: Also, my implementation requires the lists to be changed quite often (by users that know the class interface), but seldom otherwise.