# Cannot implictly convert List<List<T>> to IList<IList<T>>?

Tags: c#, .net, data-structures, interface, polymorphism

I have a method like

```
public IList<IList<int>> LevelOrderBottom(TreeNode root)
{   
   var result = new List<List<int>>();
   // ...
   return result;
}
```

and am getting compile-time error

> Cannot implicitly convert type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List>'
>   to
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IList>'.
>   An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

I don't understand why that doesn't work, but

```
private static IList<int> ReturnAList()
{
    return new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3, };
}
```

does?

Comment: And just today someone asked something very similar: https://stackoverflow.com/q/50526268/613130 (and I gave a possible answer)

Comment: @TJWolschon No, quite different. `IList<>` is an interface of `List<>`, and `List<>` can be casted to `IList<>` without changing it (it is a reference)

Comment: When you have `IList<IList<int>>`, you can add anything to it that implements `IList<int>`. When you have `List<List<int>>`, the only thing you can add to it is `List<int>`. So if you have a reference R to `List<List<int>>` where R is typed `IList<IList<int>>`, the static type checking will allow you to add things that the actual object doesn't. Casting a reference is for when the thing it refers to *actually is* the type you're casting to. In this case, it isn't.