# Substituting List<IFoo> with List<Foo that implements IFoo>

Tags: c#, interface, liskov-substitution-principle

I am having issues with filling an object with values.
One of the properties is `List<IFoo> foos`

later when I want to fill my model with data from my database I want to put `List<Foo>` in place on that property.

I thought since `Foo` correctly implements the `IFoo` interface this should work (right?) but I get an error saying that I can't implicity convert `List<Foo>` to `List<IFoo>`

I think I am looking past something...
Thank you for helping out in advance

Comment: Got a small code sample?

Comment: You cannot convert List<Foo> to List<IFoo> .. but you can cast it: `foos.Cast<IFoo>().ToList()`

Comment: You sure you don't want to convert? `List<IFoo> fooBar = myFoos.ToList<IFoo>();`

Comment: Yeah sure, giveme a moment and I''ll edit the post

Comment: @PimSchwippert - No need to edit, you can convert your `Foos` to `IFoos` using `ToList<IFoo>()`

Comment: @JonH I got a json field in my settings table. that settings field can be all sorts of different kinds of settings which is why I made an interface ISettings that doesn't do anything but is just there as a way for me to use implementations like my CustomField which implements the ISetting interface. Does that clear anything up?

Comment: I see, I think that's indeed what I am looking for. Thank you! @JonH

Comment: @PimSchwippert - No one explains it more clearer than JonSkeet: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8925400/cast-listt-to-listinterface

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply put, a `List<Sheep>` is **not** a `List<IAnimal>`even if each `Sheep` is an `IAnimal`. Because a `List<IAnimal>` would allow me to `.Add(new BigBadWolf())` which the `List<Sheep>` can never allow.

What you can do is create a **new** `List<IAnimal>` with all your `Sheep` in it by calling `sheep.ToList<IAnimal>()`.

Comment: That's a really nice, easy to understand example.

Comment: That's very understandable. One question though. if Sheep has a property `bool IsShaved` and IAnimal does not, but I know that my `List<IAnimal>` currently only contains `Sheep`, can I cast `List<IAnimal>` back to Sheep to access the propert `IsShaved`?

Comment: @PimSchwippert If your animals are definitely all sheep, you can use `animalList.Cast<Sheep>()` to get an `IEnumerable<Sheep>`. If you are not sure if there are sheep but you want to do something with all sheep, you can use `animalList.OfType<Sheep>()` to also get an `IEnumerable<Sheep>`. Don't forget to add `using System.Linq;` on top of your file if you do that.

Comment: Alright, thank you so much! :)

Answer (score 0):

Given types IFoo and Foo:

```
interface IFoo
{
}

class Foo : IFoo
{
}
```

You **can** create a `List<IFoo>`, populate with instances of `Foo` and assign to the property/field/variable:

```
private List<IFoo> foos;

void GetFoos()
{
    foos = new List<IFoo> { new Foo() };
}
```

But you **can't** assign `List<Foo>` to `List<IFoo>`:

```
foos = new List<Foo> { new Foo() };
```