# Could not create an instance of type . Type is an interface or abstract class and cannot be instantiated

Tags: c#, asp.net, rest, asp.net-web-api, automapper

I understand the below solution works fine, however it doesnt seems to be working for collection. Getting "Cannot implicitly convert type `System.Collections.Generic.IList<Something>` to `System.Collections.Generic.IList<ISomething>`. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)" if I tried to assign `IList<Something>` to `IList<ISomething>` in the constructor. Any suggestions?

Working code:

```html
public class Foo
{ 
    public int Number { get; private set; }

    public ISomething IsSomething { get; private set; }

    public Foo(int number, Something concreteType)
    {
        Number = number;
        IsSomething = concreteType;
    }
}
```

Not works:

```html
public class Foo
{ 
    public int Number { get; private set; }

    public IList<ISomething> IsSomething { get; private set; }

    public Foo(int number, IList<Something> concreteType)
    {
        Number = number;
        IsSomething = concreteType; //getting error
    }
}
```

ConvertAll seems to be fixed the issue.

Comment: I can´t see where you´re using a list at all. Anyway an `IList<Derived>` is simply not an `IList<Base>`. Imagine it were: You could cast to the base-class list and add instances of `AnotherDerivedClass` into that list: `((ILlist<ISomething>)myList).Add(new MyEvilType())`. Now you´d have a list of different types. I doubt that´s what you want, is it?

Comment: Please provide [mcve].

Comment: I can't get your error if I code the ctor as : public Foo(int number, IList<ISomething> somethings) and create the Foo as : Foo foo = new Foo(1, new List<ISomething>(){ new Something()});

Comment: Are you getting the error in the title or the error in the body of your question? They're different. Your code supports the error in the body of the question, but not the one in the title. Please clarify what you're actually asking about here.

Comment: The title error (i.e.Could not create an instance of type . Type is an interface or abstract class and cannot be instantiated) getting when I dont use the constructor. I get  "Cannot implicitly convert type System.Collections.Generic.IList<Something> to System.Collections.Generic.IList<ISomething>. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)" when i tried use the constructor & assign IsSomething = concreteType. Hope this is clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @HimBromBeere pointed out, if what you tried was allowed these lists would become of different types and breaks type safety. You can refer to the excellent answer by JonSkeet here : [Cast List<T> to List<Interface>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8925400/cast-listt-to-listinterface)

To make your code work, you'll have to convert as mentioned in JonSkeet's answer or you can also use the ConvertAll method.

```
public class Foo
{ 
  public int Number { get; private set; }
  public IList<ISomething> IsSomething { get; private set; }
  public Foo(int number, IList<Something> concreteType)
  {
    Number = number;

    // convert here, creates a new list
    IsSomething = concreteType.ConvertAll(x => (ISomething)x);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Ram. This takes me to next step but getting different errors, please see my updated post

Comment: Thanks, I've accepted this as answer. Will post my new issue separately.