# Is there any workaround for CS0266: Cannot implicitly convert type ... (IList<Interface>)?

Tags: c#, inheritance, interface

I have a class which implements an interface. A second class implements an IList<> of this first class. I need to assign this second class to a generic property which is an IList<> of the interface.

This is a demo for the code I use:

```
public class SODemo
{
    public SODemo()
    {
        ClassWithIListOfClassWithInterface classWithIList = new ClassWithIListOfClassWithInterface();

        IList<IDemoInterface> listOfInterfaces;

        // CS0266: Cannot implicitly convert type ...
        listOfInterfaces = classWithIList;
    }
}

public class ClassWithInterface : IDemoInterface
{
    // ...
}

public class ClassWithIListOfClassWithInterface : IList<ClassWithInterface>
{
    // ...
}
```

From answers on similar problems I found out that it seems not work at all.

**Why do I need this?**
I have a lot of classes which are implemented like `ClassWithIListOfClassWithInterface` and I need a generic handler for them.

**Question:**

My goal is to access each element in `listOfInterfaces` through the methods implemented in the interface.

Is there any alternative I can use?

**Edit**
I already tried this

```
listOfInterfaces = (IList<IDemoInterface>)classWithIList;
```

but then I get an `System.InvalidCastException` at runtime.

Comment: Can you use `IEnumerable` instead of `ILIst` for the local variable?

Comment: @DStanley No, I need the Add() Remove() ... stuff and for performance reasons I need List()

Comment: Then you can't use a more generic variable. The underlying list will be more specific and could cause runtime errors (e.g. trying to add a `ClassWithInterface2` to an `List<ClassWithInterface>`). The variable type just tells the compiler what operations are allowed on the underlying object.

Comment: @DStanley Thanks for the hint. That sounds disturbing. Do you have a concrete example?

Comment: The [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8925442/1081897) of the marked duplicate is a good example.

Comment: @DStanley Does that affect me when I don't use any casts or "ToList()" methods?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean  - a `List<Banana>` is _not_ an `IList<Fruit>` because you cannot add an `Apple` to it. So in your case you can't use a more generic variable to reference a more specific collection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not with your class itself, but rather with the conversion between `IList<IDemoInterface>` and `IList<ClassWithInterface>`.

`IList<T>` in C# are said to be **"invariant in T"**. This means that you **cannot** make conversions between `IList<T1>` and `IList<T2>` directly, even if they have an inheritance relationship.

What you can do is to create an `IList<IDemoInterface>` and copy every element from your source `IList<ClassWithInterface>` to it. Of course that'd be rather cumbersome, so the LINQ way of doing it is that:

```
listOfInterfaces = classWithIList.Cast<IDemoInterface>().ToList();
```

Comment: If you need more information check out [these docs on variance (covariance and contravariane)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/generics/covariance-and-contravariance). I'd also suggest you using an `IEnumerable<IDemoInterface>` instead of `IList<IDemoInterface>`, because it is more LINQ-friendly and it makes the evaluation of the collection lazy, and your code more generic.

Comment: I know what the cause of the problem ist. Creating a copy is no option.

Comment: Note that this does not copy the _items_ in the list - it creates a _new_ list with references to the same items (just through a different interface).