# C# casting generics to interfaces

Tags: c#, generics

I have a method with the following signature:

```
public IDisposable RegisterSubscriber<T>(T subscriber)
    where T : MessageBusSubscriber<IMessageBusEvent>
{
    
}
```

I am trying to call this from a `MessageBusSubscriber<MoveEvent>`:

```
public class MoveSubscriber : MessageBusSubscriber<MoveEvent>
{ 
    private readonly IDisposable _subscription;

    public MoveSubscriber(MessageBus bus)
    {
        _subscription = bus.RegisterSubscriber(this);
    }
}

public class MoveEvent : IMessageBusEvent {}

public interface IMessageBusEvent { }
```

I get the following error: `CS0311  The type 'MoveSubscriber' cannot be used as type parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'MessageBus.RegisterSubscriber<T>(T)'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'MoveSubscriber' to 'MessageBusSubscriber<IMessageBusEvent>'.`

Am I missing something or should this work, I was under the impression that a class that uses a generic restricted to a certain interface should allow a class that implements said interface in it's place.

e.g A `MessageBusSubscriber<MoveEvent>` is a `MessageBusSubscriber<IMessageBusEvent>` so should be allowed.

Thanks

Comment: No, `MessageBusSubscriber<MoveEvent>` is not `MessageBusSubscriber<IMessageBusEvent>`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/8925400/11683?

Comment: You can see that too : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2033912/c-sharp-variance-problem-assigning-listderived-as-listbase

Comment: It's a bit of a special case here, but @GSerg is probably right. This is an instance of the Lion/Giraffe/Animal problem.