Is this syntax and method for making a deep copy of a List of interfaces in VB.NET, constructing new instances from interfaces, flawed?
I'm learning VB.NET and finding that there are dozens of ways to get the same behavior. So I'd like to know if there's a better way to solve the following case.
Assume a simple interface and a class that implements it:
Public Interface IX
    ReadOnly Property Name As String
End Interface
Public Class X
    Implements IX
    Public ReadOnly Property Name As String = "Hello" Implements IX.Name
End Class

Assume another interface and another class that implements it:
Public Interface IY
    ReadOnly Property R As IEnumerable(Of IX)
End Interface
Public Class Y
    Implements IY
    Public Sub New(r As IEnumerable(Of IX))
        mR = r.Select(Of X)(Function(a As IX, i As Integer) New X).Select(Of IX)(Function(a As X, i As Integer) a).ToList
    End Sub
    Protected mR As List(Of IX)
    Public ReadOnly Property R As IEnumerable(Of IX) Implements IY.R
        Get
            Return mR
        End Get
    End Property
End Class

Then here's three lines I'll discuss:
Dim a As New List(Of IX) From {New X, New X}
Dim b As New Y(a)
Dim c As New Y(b.R)

What I want is for the first line to construct two X instances, then construct a List of just their interfaces. Then the second line should construct a Y instance using that List, but where the constructor will construct two more X instances to be copies of the original pair, which it will hold in its own instance. Then the third line does about the same, constructing a second Y instance, but this time using the list from b to do it -- and yes, constructing two more X instances in the process.
By the end of those three statements I expect six instances of X to be floating around and two instances of Y. a will hold references to two of them. b will hold references to two more of them. And c will hold references to the last two of them.
The single line in the body of Y's constructor is a very long line. I iterate through each interface, make an X from it to get a new instance, then slice it back to just an interface, finally collecting up the entire iteration to make a List from it. I believe it does perform as described above. But I'm not sure if all of that is necessary.
Is there a preferred way to handle this? Is there something wrong with the way I handled it?
added for Craig's comment below
I thought just as you did about the second Select. And that is the first way I chose to write it. But as you can see:

the compiler/IDE doesn't like it.
Apparently, it isn't willing (probably for good reason) to take the assumption that a request to iterate through a bunch of X's to make a List of them can't be automatically converted to a request to iterate through a bunch of interfaces of IX's to make a List of those, instead. I could pass an X as a parameter to a function expecting an IX. And that works, of course, as it should. But here? It doesn't seem to want to go that far.

You mention "slicing" which is a C++ concept which, as far as I know, is not applicable to .NET; a client can always discover that instances of IX are actually X and cast to it, though I would always consider that to be questionable style.

The second Select in the ctor of Y doesn't seem to actually do anything; it still ends up returning the ref which was created in the first Select.

@Craig I'm using a term I made up to communicate by best to others, and not intending to exhibit any sophistication at all. As far as the second Select it was added only after seeing the IDE tell me that it wouldn't compile without it. I'll add an image to show you what I mean.

I see why that happened, the function in the Select was deduced to return X and List does not support variance on its types (note that this is different from IEnumerable(Of T)).  You might alternatively explicitly state the return type on the lambda or (I think) use Cast(Of IX) to convert your enumerable to the right type.

@Craig Thanks. I'll try that. Update: It appears to "like it," compiles it, and runs it fine. So that is definitely an improvement! How would you like to proceed? It looks to me as if there won't be a better answer to my question. So I would take your answer, not feeling any need to wait for better. Up to you. And thanks! That actually dealt with a problem I faced. And I was thinking like you did about it. You really helped me think better. :)

I'm confused about the very premise of your code, which seems to be that there is exactly one concrete type that implements each interface, so when you see interface IX you know you must create concrete type X. The very point of interfaces is that several unrelated concrete objects may implement the same interface. With a strict one to one relationship, the interfaces are pointless and shouldn't be used. As for your latest addition, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/8925400/11683.

@GSerg You are asking about the larger purposes I have in mind. And that would be a very different question. I'm trying to learn the language right now. Not ask for design help on larger projects (which I'm not yet prepared to handle.) One step at a time. I need to learn the syntax and the associated semantics first. And variant syntax for the same semantics. I hope to write clear code. But I'm not prepared to do that if I'm not adequately informed. Also, as I understand it, questions here are supposed to be narrow and focused. Not drawn out design questions. Am I wrong?

@GSerg Finally, you write, "The very point of interfaces is that several unrelated concrete objects may implement the same interface." This statement is arguable. But here, in comments, wouldn't be the place for it. There are plenty of books on the topic, in fact, that dig deeply into when, if, how, where, etc. The first one coming to mind is Dependency Injection: Principles, Practices, and Patterns. But it is only one of many. I don't want to engage the topic here. I'm just learning the language right now. Not preparing for a chalkboard presentation to a room full of programmers.

No, I didn't ask about purposes you had in mind. You have laid out a specific assumption in your code, that when you see an interface IX in the list, you should create concrete object X. This is an unusual assumption, and it's not clear where you are going with it. As you can see from your own code, Y does not even process the actual instances of IX, it's only interested in how many there are in the list, so that the Public Sub New(r As IEnumerable(Of IX)) could be replaced with Public Sub New(HowManyToCreate As Integer) and called as New Y(a.Count).

@GSerg I created as simple an example as I felt would get the question about syntax for a specific semantic across. And I succeeded, as Craig gave me exactly what I was looking to get. None of what I wrote has any purpose at all. It's just a meaningless, stripped-down example case so that I could communicate about the syntax/semantics question at hand. And it achieved its purpose well, I think. If you were writing my question, you might approach it the way you suggest. Are you asking me to change the text of my question, after it has already achieved its purpose?
