# EF - Mapping generic class to Complex Type

Tags: c#, entity-framework

It is possible to map generic class to complex type?
I have small class that 3 properties - string, int and generic type, and want to map the string and the int (the string is actually the serialized generic type) to a complex type.

I assume that it isn't possible as the generic class "FQDN" is `MyGenericClass<somclass>` and the complex type conceptional type is just `MyGenericClass` Is there clever solution or I'll have to define ComplexType for each usage of the generic class?

Comment: EF does not allow mapping generic types (be it complex or entity type)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if i understood you correctly, but why don't you use a custom cast by overriding the conversion operator. In the following example i casted my generic complex class implicitly to a non-generic class.

Read more @ [How do I provide custom cast support for my class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1407689/how-do-i-provide-custom-cast-support-for-my-class)

```
public class ClassComplex<T> 
{
    public T MyGenericValue { get; set; }
    public string MyStringValue { get; set; }
    public int MyIntValue { get; set; }

    public static implicit operator ClassComplex(ClassComplex<T> a)
    {
        return new ClassComplex() { MyIntValue = a.MyIntValue , MyStringValue = a.MyStringValue };
    }
}

public class ClassComplex
{
    public string MyStringValue { get; set; }
    public int MyIntValue { get; set; }
}

public class Test
{
    public Test()
    {
        ClassComplex<int> ccg = new ClassComplex<int>();
        ccg.MyGenericValue = 1;
        ccg.MyIntValue = 2;
        ccg.MyStringValue = "3";

        ClassComplex cc = ccg;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is great idea, however, ASAIK the entity framework preforms the mapping according to the class name, so I would be either forced to use `ClassComplex` in the dto object,  loosing the point of the generic type.