# Cast an object to an array of string?

Tags: c#, linq, casting

I have this code:

```
Strutture = from Ricettivito s in Strutture
            where s.ServiziAttivi.Cast<string>().Intersect(IDSServizi).Count() == IDSServizi.Count()
            select s;
```

I need to:

1. Cast ServiziAttivi (which is a list of MyService) into a list of string (which must contains MyService.UniqueID)
2. Than, check if this list contains each elements of IDSServizi (which is a list of string).

But seems I cannot doint that conversion?

Comment: Only you can tell us why you can't do that conversion - what's the error message?

Comment: `Unable to cast object of type 'Ricettivita.MyService' to type 'System.String'.`

Comment: I need to extract `Ricettivito` which `ServiziAttivi` that contains each values inside IDSServizi

Comment: Rather than casting, try `.Select`-ing the `UniqueID` from the `ServiziAttivi`-list.

Comment: Check this thread. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1407689/how-do-i-provide-custom-cast-support-for-my-class

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First cast to `.Cast<Ricettivita.MyService>()` then select a string property.

```
    where s.ServiziAttivi
             .Cast<Ricettivita.MyService>()
             .Select(x=>x.UniqueID).Intersect(IDSServizi).Count()
```

Comment: If OP did a .ToList() would they need a cast, first? Assuming OPs custom collection class inherits from Enumerable in some way.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use `Select` instead of `Cast`:

```
Strutture = from Ricettivito s in Strutture
            where s.ServiziAttivi.Select(x => (string)x.UniqueID).Intersect(IDSServizi).Count() == IDSServizi.Count()
            select s;
```

Comment: I can't. Check the answer to @Michael Perrenoud