# Allow casting a string to my Class

Tags: c#, casting

I have a class called `SystemUser` as defined below:

```
    public class SystemUser
    {
        public int userID;
        public string userName;
        public string email;

        public SystemUser(int userId, string userName, string email)
        {
            this.userID = userId;
            this.userName = userName;
            this.email = email;
        }

        public static explicit operator System.String(SystemUser su)
        {
            return su.userName;
        }

        public static implicit operator SystemUser(System.String s)
        {
            SystemUser thing = new SystemUser(-1, s);
            return thing;
        }
    }
```

From what I'm able to determine, this should allow me to perform the following, where `user` is a variable of type `object`:

```
List<SystemUser> systemUsers = new List<SystemUser>();
systemUsers.Add((SystemUser)user); // causes exception
```

However, if `user` is a string, I always get the InvalidCastException: "Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'SystemUser'"

What am I missing here?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I provide custom cast support for my class?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1407689/how-do-i-provide-custom-cast-support-for-my-class)

Comment: although this is possible technically, this is **very bad** design.

Comment: Are you sure you don't want that second operator to be `explicit`?

Comment: @AK_, can you explain why this is such bad design?

Comment: @Jimmy because conversions are intended to move the same thing between different representations. i.e. the number 5 can be stored in an int or a double, but it remains the number 5. A string represents some text, a `User` object represents the abstract concept of a user within the system. these are different "things" . what you are looking for is probably the ToString() function, and a constructor reciving a string parameter, or maybe Json Serialization

Comment: @AK_ That makes sense. Thank you. I think I'll have to give up on the casting in this situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like your `user` variable is of type `object`. You've only provided conversion support for the following scenarios:

- `string` ⇒ `SystemUser`
- `SystemUser` ⇒ `string`

While your `user` variable might contain a reference to an instance of `string`, it can't be implicitly downcast to `string`.

`string` (or any other type, for that matter) can be implicitly upcast to `object` (since `string is object` evaluates to `true`), the converse is not possible. An `object` instance can't be implicitly downcast to `string` since `object is string` evaluates to `false`.

You can:

- explicitly cast your `object` to `string` and then to `SystemUser`, or

  ```
  object     user     = GetStringRepresentingUser() ;
  SystemUser instance = (SystemUser)(string)user ;
  ```
- change the data type of `user` to `string`

  ```
  string     user     = GetStringRepresentingUser() ;
  SystemUser instance = (SystemUser)user ;
  ```

**Edited to Note:**

Adding overloads may help you here. You can do something like this:

```
public static SystemUser GetSystemUser( object o )
{
  SystemUser instance ;
  if ( o is string )
  {
    instance = GetSystemUser( (string) o ) ;
  }
  else
  {
    instance = (SystemUser) o ;
  }
  return instance ;
}
public static SystemUser GetSystemUser( string s )
{
  return (SystemUser) s ;
}
```

You might also consider using the `Parse()``TryParse()` idiom:

```
public static SystemUser Parse( string s )
{
  // parse the string and construct a SystemUser instance
  // throw a suitable exception if the parse is unsuccessful
}
public static bool TryParse( string s , out SystemUser instance )
{
  // as above, except no exception is thrown on error.
  // instead, return true or false, setting instance to default(SystemUser) (null)
  // if the conversion wasnt' possible.
}
```

Using `Parse()`/`TryParse()` is likely to get more easily understood as well.

Not matter how you do it, at some point you're going to have to look at your `object` and check its type:

- If its actually a string, excplicity downcast to `string` and deserialize (parse) it back into an instance of your class, or...
- If it's not a string, it must be an instance of your type: excplicity downcast it.

Comment: Would it be possible to avoid the string cast by writing my custom cast on object instead of string? `user` can be either of type SystemUser or string before the cast, so I'm trying to avoid having to check the type.

Comment: No. You'll get `error CS0553: 'Foo.Bar.implicit operator Foo.Bar(object)': user-defined conversions to or from a base class are not allowed`. Why don't you use *overloading* to accomplish what you want? (see my answer for details).

Comment: Well that makes a lot more sense than what I was trying to do. Thanks for your help!