# DataGridView trying to cast from string to object

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I have a custom control whose `Value` property is an object. The control also has a `Text` property which, depending on the object, displays an object's string property.

This custom control is hosted within a `DataGridView` and I implemented the required interface `IDataGridViewEditingControl` to get it working. I also have 2 classes inheriting from `DataGridViewColumn` and `DataGridViewTextBoxCell`.

The CustomerTypeDto class:

```
public class CustomerTypeDto
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public int Description {get; set}
    //Other properties...
}
```

One remaining problem is that after I select a value from the control and the DataGridView tries to end the cell edit, I get the following exception:

> System.FormatException: Invalid cast from 'System.String' to 'CustomerTypeDto'. ---> System.InvalidCastException: Invalid cast from 'System.String' to 'CustomerTypeDto'.
>      at System.Convert.DefaultToType(IConvertible value, Type targetType, IFormatProvider provider)
>      at System.String.System.IConvertible.ToType(Type type, IFormatProvider provider)
>      at System.Convert.ChangeType(Object value, Type conversionType, IFormatProvider provider)
>      at System.Windows.Forms.Formatter.ChangeType(Object value, Type type, IFormatProvider formatInfo)
>      --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>      at System.Windows.Forms.Formatter.ChangeType(Object value, Type type, IFormatProvider formatInfo)
>      at System.Windows.Forms.Formatter.ParseObjectInternal(Object value, Type targetType, Type sourceType, TypeConverter targetConverter, TypeConverter sourceConverter, IFormatProvider formatInfo, Object formattedNullValue)
>      at System.Windows.Forms.Formatter.ParseObject(Object value, Type targetType, Type sourceType, TypeConverter targetConverter, TypeConverter sourceConverter, IFormatProvider formatInfo, Object formattedNullValue, Object dataSourceNullValue)
>      at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCell.ParseFormattedValueInternal(Type valueType, Object formattedValue, DataGridViewCellStyle cellStyle, TypeConverter formattedValueTypeConverter, TypeConverter valueTypeConverter)
>      at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCell.ParseFormattedValue(Object formattedValue, DataGridViewCellStyle cellStyle, TypeConverter formattedValueTypeConverter, TypeConverter valueTypeConverter)
>      at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.PushFormattedValue(DataGridViewCell& dataGridViewCurrentCell, Object formattedValue, Exception& exception)

Which method or property do I need to override so that the `DataGridView` can cast from my object to string and vice-versa.

And should I inherit from `DataGridViewTextBoxCell` or from `DataGridViewCell` directly?

**EDIT**

This is my cell class:

```
public class CustomerTypeCell : DataGridViewTextBoxCell
{
    public CustomerTypeCell()
        : base()
    { }

    public override void InitializeEditingControl(int rowIndex, object initialFormattedValue, DataGridViewCellStyle dataGridViewCellStyle)
    {
        base.InitializeEditingControl(rowIndex, initialFormattedValue, dataGridViewCellStyle);

        CustomControl ctl = DataGridView.EditingControl as CustomControl;

        if (this.Value == null)
            ctl.Value = (CustomerTypeDto)this.DefaultNewRowValue;
        else
            ctl.Value = (CustomerTypeDto)this.Value;
    }

    public override Type EditType
    {
        get { return typeof(CustomControl); }
    }

    public override Type ValueType
    {
        get { return typeof(CustomerTypeDto); }
    }

    public override object DefaultNewRowValue
    {
        get { return null; }
    }

    public override object ParseFormattedValue(object formattedValue, DataGridViewCellStyle cellStyle, TypeConverter formattedValueTypeConverter, TypeConverter valueTypeConverter)
    {
        return base.ParseFormattedValue(formattedValue, cellStyle, formattedValueTypeConverter, valueTypeConverter);
    }
}
```

The property `FormattedValueType` in `DataGridViewTextBoxCell` always returns string.

And in the method `ParseFormattedValue` above, it's trying to cast from string to my object. The description of this method :

> Converts a value formatted for display to an actual cell value.

But this doesn't make sense because the `Value` is of type `CustomerTypeDto`, so how is this parsing going to work?

Basically what I'm trying to do is let the user select a `CustomerType` object from my custom control. This object should be the cell's value, and the value's text (in this case the `Description` property) is displayed as a string in the cell.

I do not understand why the `DataGridView` wants to parse the string in an object if I already have the object in the cell's value property.

Comment: Can you add an example of the text in the cell and the definition of the CustomerTypeDto class?

Comment: @Ivan-Mark Debono  t looks likes PwnyExpress was already on the right track. I found a similar question here on stack overflow at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1407689/how-do-i-provide-custom-cast-support-for-my-class

Comment: I deleted my answer after I re-read your comment.  I'm unclear as to why a search filter that is user entered requires an ID.  Is there a way you can change this to just taking a `string`?

Comment: The ID is needed so that the a valid CustomerType object can be used in the Customer.CustomerType property. The Customer object is then sent back to the server (WebApi 2) and the graph is saved back in the db. I have a sample project here... https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=ba8db0c447edb711%211334

Comment: How exactly do you do the databinding? (thus how do you bind the list of CustomerTypeDto's to the view / to the columns/fields). In the worst case it could be that the problem happens when he tries to update/add the data in the datasource but that would be if you made an error with the binding

Comment: Data binding is done using a binding source.

Answer (score 2):

if you want to implement your value ahead of time,
use method `e.ParsingApplied = true;`after you implement to `e.Value = (ObjOfYourType)`
i have used it in event `CellParsing` that is caused before dropping an exception.

Answer (score 1):

Your `CustomerTypeDto` class needs an explicit cast operator for the string type.

```
class CustomerTypeDto
{
    // string -> CustomerTypeDto
    public static explicit operator CustomerTypeDto(string s)
    {
        CustomerTypeDto ctd = new CustomerTypeDto();
        // ... do something with the string.
        return ctd;
    }
    // CustomerTypeDto -> string
    public static explicit operator String(CustomerTypeDto ctd)
    {
        return ctd.toString();
        // or some other way to return it's string value.
    }
    // other stuff...
}
```

So you can do things like this:

```
return (CustomerTypeDto)someString;
```

Comment: Unfortunately this answer doesn't work for me because I keep getting the same error. Why does the `DataGridView` want to parse the string in an object anyway?

Answer (score 0):

This question is already answered with 2 working solutions in
[Custom Control in DataGridView Cell Throws FormatException When Editing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36655807/custom-control-in-datagridview-cell-throws-formatexception-when-editing)

The first answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/36656360 is only working with my comment, thus the full solution is

```
public object GetEditingControlFormattedValue (DataGridViewDataErrorContexts context)
{
  if ((context & DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Parsing) != 0)
  {
    // Here you should not return string, but your value
    return Value;
  }
  return EditingControlFormattedValue;
}

public override object ParseFormattedValue (object formattedValue,
                                            DataGridViewCellStyle cellStyle,
                                            TypeConverter formattedValueTypeConverter,
                                            TypeConverter valueTypeConverter)
{
  if (formattedValue is CustomerTypeDto)
  {
    return formattedValue;
  }
  return base.ParseFormattedValue (formattedValue, cellStyle, formattedValueTypeConverter, valueTypeConverter);
}
```

The second answer
https://stackoverflow.com/a/36668621 works as expected.