# Custom Control in DataGridView Cell Throws FormatException When Editing

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have created a custom control to edit a custom value in a DataGridView cell. I am following the example here:
 [How to: Host Controls in Windows Forms DataGridView Cells](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7tas5c80(v=vs.110).aspx)

I have a custom data class that is a member of a list of objects bound to the DataGridView.

```
internal class CustomValue
{
   // Some stuff is here.
}
```

I have created a custom control to edit the value in the cell that implements the IDataGridViewEditingControl interface.

```
internal partial class CustomValueEditControl : UserControl, IDataGridViewEditingControl
{
        DataGridView m_dataGridView;

        private bool m_valueChanged = false;

        int m_rowIndex;

        private CustomValue m_value;

        public CustomValue Value
        {
            get
            {
                return m_value;
            }
            set
            {
                m_value = value;
            }
        }

        public void ApplyCellStyleToEditingControl(DataGridViewCellStyle dataGridViewCellStyle)
        {
        }

        public DataGridView EditingControlDataGridView
        {
            get
            {
                return m_dataGridView;
            }
            set
            {
                m_dataGridView = value;
            }
        }

        public object EditingControlFormattedValue
        {
            get
            {
                return this.Value.ToString();
            }
            set
            {
                if (value is String)
                {
                    CustomValue val;
                    if (CustomValue.TryParse((String)value, out val))
                    {
                        this.Value = val;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        this.Value = new CustomValue();
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        public int EditingControlRowIndex
        {
            get
            {
                return m_rowIndex;
            }
            set
            {
                m_rowIndex = value;
            }
        }

        public bool EditingControlValueChanged
        {
            get
            {
                return m_valueChanged;
            }
            set
            {
                m_valueChanged = value;
            }
        }

        public bool EditingControlWantsInputKey(Keys keyData, bool dataGridViewWantsInputKey)
        {
            switch (keyData & Keys.KeyCode)
            {
                case Keys.Up:
                case Keys.Down:
                    return true;

                default:
                    return !dataGridViewWantsInputKey;
            }
        }

        public Cursor EditingPanelCursor
        {
            get
            {
                return base.Cursor;
            }
        }

        public object GetEditingControlFormattedValue(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts context)
        {
            return EditingControlFormattedValue;
        }

        public void PrepareEditingControlForEdit(bool selectAll)
        {
        }

        public bool RepositionEditingControlOnValueChange
        {
            get
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
}
```

I have set up a custom DataGridViewCell that descends from DataGridViewTextBoxCell so the cell just displays a string representation of the custom value until it is edited.

```
internal class CustomValueCell : DataGridViewTextBoxCell
{

    public override void InitializeEditingControl(int rowIndex, object initialFormattedValue, DataGridViewCellStyle dataGridViewCellStyle)
    {
        base.InitializeEditingControl(rowIndex, initialFormattedValue, dataGridViewCellStyle);

        CustomValueEditControl customValueEditControl = DataGridView.EditingControl as CustomValueEditControl;

        if (this.Value == null)
        {
            customValueEditControl.Value = (CustomValue)this.DefaultNewRowValue;
        }
        else
        {
            customValueEditControl.Value = (CustomValue)this.Value;
        }
    }

    public override Type EditType
    {
        get
        {
            return typeof(CustomValueEditControl);
        }
    }

    public override Type ValueType
    {
        get
        {
            return typeof(CustomValue);
        }
    }

    public override Type FormattedValueType
    {
        get
        {
            return typeof(string);
        }
    }

    public override object DefaultNewRowValue
    {
        get
        {
            return new CustomValue();
        }
    }
}
```

I have created a custom DataGridViewColumn.

```
internal class CustomValueColumn : DataGridViewColumn
{
    public CustomValueColumn()
        : base(new CustomValueCell())
    {
    }

    public override object Clone()
    {
        CustomValueColumn clone = (CustomValueColumn)base.Clone();

        return clone;
    }

    public override DataGridViewCell CellTemplate
    {
        get
        {
            return base.CellTemplate;
        }
        set
        {
            // Ensure that the cell used for the template is a CustomValueCell.
            if (value != null && !value.GetType().IsAssignableFrom(typeof(CustomValueCell)))
            {
                throw new InvalidCastException("Must be a CustomValueCell");
            }

            base.CellTemplate = value;
        }
    }
}
```

The cell shows the value of the custom type correctly, and I can use the custom control to edit the value. When I leave the editing cell, I get a System.FormatException: Invalid cast from 'System.String' to 'CustomValue' at System.Convert.DefaultToType(IConvertable value, Type targetType, IFormatProvider provider)...

At what point is it trying to cast a string to my custom value? Should this not be handled by the CustomValueEditControl.GetEditingControlFormattedValue?

Comment: It's been a while since I had to something like this, but it sounds like you need to override the `GetFormattedValue` method of the `DataGridViewCell`, see the section about it [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730881(v=vs.80).aspx#dtH1) (near the middle)

Comment: I have tried that. I think the DataGridViewTextBoxCell already overrides that to return a string from the object.

Answer (score 2):

So I ended up solving this by implementing a TypeConverter class.

```
internal class CustomValueTypeConverter : TypeConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, Type sourceType)
    {
        if (sourceType == typeof(string))
        {
            return true;
        }

        return base.CanConvertFrom(context, sourceType);
    }

    public override bool CanConvertTo(ITypeDescriptorContext context, Type destinationType)
    {
        if (destinationType == typeof(string))
        {
            return true;
        }

        return base.CanConvertTo(context, destinationType);
    }

    public override object ConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture, object value)
    {
        if (value is string)
        {
            CustomValue customValue;

            if (CustomValue.TryParse((string)value, out customValue))
            {
                return customValue;
            }
        }

        return base.ConvertFrom(context, culture, value);
    }

    public override object ConvertTo(ITypeDescriptorContext context, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture, object value, Type destinationType)
    {
        if (destinationType == typeof(string))
        {
            value.ToString();
        }

        return base.ConvertTo(context, culture, value, destinationType);
    }
}
```

Then I had to decorate the CustomValue class with a TypeConverterAttribute.

```
[TypeConverter(typeof(CustomValueTypeConverter))]
internal class CustomValue
{
  // Some stuff here.
}
```

Comment: This is the correct approach. However, the workaround I described above omits parsing and therefore in my opinion is the safer way.

Comment: I think this is working but where there is the line "value.ToString();" that should probably be "return value.ToString();"

Answer (score 1):

> At what point is it trying to cast a string to my custom value? Should this not be handled by the CustomValueEditControl.GetEditingControlFormattedValue?

Exactly. But the sample you are based on does not handle it correctly. You should use something like this:

```
public object GetEditingControlFormattedValue(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts context)
{
    if ((context & DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Parsing) != 0)
    {
        // Here you should not return string, but your value
        return Value;
    }
    return EditingControlFormattedValue;
}
```

If you return `string` (which `EditingControlFormattedValue` property does), then the `DataGridView` will try to convert it to `CustomValue` object. The example works because `DateTime` has associated [`TypeConverter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.typeconverter(v=vs.110).aspx) while your class apparently doesn't have.

Comment: I think I have been down this road somehow. If GetEditingControlFormattedValue returns a CustomValue, then I get a System.ArgumentException: Formatted value of the cell has the wrong type.

If I change the FormattedValueType property of the cell to CustomValue, then the cell does not show the string representation when the cell is not being edited.

Comment: Please see the code snippet in the answer - that's all you need to do. Add the `if` statement and handle differently `DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Parsing` flag,

Comment: @ZoltanF is right, it will throw an exception. But you can work around that with 
`override ParseFormattedValue (..) { 
if (formattedValue is CustomValue)
 return formattedValue;
return base.ParseFormattedValue (..);
}`