# C#: explicit typeconversion

Tags: c#

Im currently struggling to find a solution to an exercise. 
How can i modify ClassA so that the explicit typeconversion in the second part is possible?

```
class ClassA {
public int MyValue = 0;
public string MyText = "Hello World!";

//Code to impl
}

ClassA myObject = new ClassA();
myObject.MyValue = 42;
myObject.MyText = "Hi!"
int x = (int)myObject;
string str = (string)myObject;
```

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xhbhezf4.aspx

Comment: @TZHX That question covers *implicit* type conversion.

Comment: A better duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1407689/how-do-i-provide-custom-cast-support-for-my-class

Answer (score -1):

Something like this in your `ClassA` definition should work:

```
public static explicit operator int(ClassA a)
{
    return a.MyValue;
}

public static explicit operator string(ClassA a)
{
    return a.MyText;
}
```

(I actually can't remember if this case would require `implicit` or `explicit`, and can't test it at the moment.  It's worth testing both for your needs.)

Though it's a little strange why you'd want to do that, instead of just grabbing these public values directly:

```
int x = myObject.MyValue;
string str = myObject.MyText;
```

Comment: thank you, thats what i missed

Comment: @David Not sure why you edited your answer; OP was asking for *explicit* conversion, so the original solution was fine.

Comment: @poke: I was wavering back and forth between the two, actually.  It's been a *long* time since I've done this, so I wasn't sure which.

Answer (score -2):

You define an explicit conversion.

The trick here is the EXPLICIT keywork.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xhbhezf4.aspx

has examples of that.

Basically: the class must implement a stateic explicit operator in the for like...

```
// Must be defined inside a class called Fahrenheit:
public static explicit operator Celsius(Fahrenheit fahr)
{
    return new Celsius((5.0f / 9.0f) * (fahr.degrees - 32));
}
```