# What is this C# Syntax called and what does it do?

Tags: c#, .net, syntax, httpwebrequest

I am learning C# and I am a beginner. I wanted to request a URL for a hardware project (raspberry pi server controlling curtains) It works but I don't understand this line below:

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create(rpiIp.text);
```

I don't understand what the "(HttpWebRequest)" bit is for and how it affects the "WebRequest.Create();" Method.

Can someone explain?

Thanks a lot
James

Comment: `WebRequest().Create()` returns an object of type `WebRequest` (which is an **abstract** class - a base class for others, that cannot be instantiated on its own, really). However, if you need to use properties and methods that are defined on the descendant class, like `HttpWebRequest`, you must **type-cast** the return type to the concrete, derived class that you need/want

Comment: The **(HttpWebRequest)** is called a cast, and is an instruction to the compiler to both ensure that the assignment RHS is valid as an instance of this type, and to only allow assignment to a LHS of this type.

Comment: What language is the RPi server written in?

Comment: Python, using flask library and GPIO library. I hate python but I can't be bothered with c socket programming for the far superior C gpio library

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is called an **Explicit Cast**. From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bw00b1dc(v=vs.110).aspx):

> **Explicit conversions (casts)**: Explicit conversions require a cast operator. Casting is required when information might be lost in the conversion, or when the conversion might not succeed for other reasons.  Typical examples include numeric conversion to a type that has less precision or a smaller range, and conversion of a base-class instance to a derived class

The method `WebRequest.Create` returns an object of type `WebRequest`, which is an abstract class, meaning an instance of it cannot be created, only an underlying derived type which inherits from `WebRequest`. What the cast is doing in this case is telling the compiler: *"Listen, i know `Create` actually returns an [`HttpWebRequest`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httprequestmessage(v=vs.118).aspx) from this method, so let me treat it like one"*. When the cast is being done, it will either succeed if the actual type is a `HttpWebRequest` or it will throw an [`InvalidCastException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.invalidcastexception(v=vs.110).aspx) if it isn`t

Comment: It is probably helpful to point out that an Explicit Cast differs from an Implicit Cast.  See this post from another C# beginner: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1176641/explicit-and-implicit-c-sharp/1176680#1176680